# How to setup standalone Controller only once before all test cases in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, controller

I am writing unit tests for controller. I am mocking service layer and using standalone setup for rest controller.

ProductSupplierControllerUnitTest.java

```
public class ProductSupplierControllerUnitTest {

    @Mock
    private ProductSupplierService productSupplierService;

    @InjectMocks
    private ProductSupplierRestController productSupplierRestController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(productSupplierRestController)
                .setControllerAdvice(new ServiceExceptionHandler()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void productNotFound() throws Exception {

        Long incorrectProductId = 2L;

        Mockito.when(productSupplierService.getProductSuppliers(incorrectProductId, tenantId))
                .thenThrow(new EntityNotFoundException(Product.class, String.valueOf(incorrectProductId)));

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(prepareRequestUrl(incorrectProductId))
                .requestAttr(TENANT_ID, tenantId).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);

        mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andExpect(status().isNotFound())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)).andExpect(jsonPath("$.message",
                        is(String.format("Product was not found for parameter(s) %s", incorrectProductId))));

        Mockito.verify(productSupplierService, times(1)).getProductSuppliers(incorrectProductId, tenantId);
        Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(productSupplierService);
    }

    @Test
    public void getProductSuppliersSuccess() throws Exception {

        Map<String, List<? extends BaseDTO>> result = new HashMap<>(0);
        ProductSupplierDTO productSupplierDTO = new ProductSupplierDTO();
        productSupplierDTO.setSupplierId(correctSupplierId);
        productSupplierDTO.setBuyPrice(validBuyPrice);
        productSupplierDTO.setDefaultSupplier(isDefaultSupplier);

        result.put("product_suppliers", Collections.singletonList(productSupplierDTO));

        Mockito.when(productSupplierService.getProductSuppliers(productId, tenantId)).thenReturn(result);

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(prepareRequestUrl(productId))
                .requestAttr(TENANT_ID, tenantId).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);

        mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.product_suppliers", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.product_suppliers[0].supplier_id", is(correctSupplierId.intValue())))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.product_suppliers[0].buy_price", is(validBuyPrice)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.product_suppliers[0].default_supplier", is(isDefaultSupplier)));

        Mockito.verify(productSupplierService, times(1)).getProductSuppliers(productId, tenantId);
        Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(productSupplierService);
    }

    // some more tests
}
```

Tests are working fine but problem is that this standalone setup is done before every test case, for every test case controller's method are mapped to url and Spring FrameworkServlet initialized.

Is it possible to do this initialization only once for all test cases ? Because I want to reduce test time.

**EDIT** : I have changed my code to following and it works as expected. Question is that is it right approach for tests?

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ProductSupplierControllerUnitTest {

    @Mock
    private ProductSupplierService productSupplierService;

    @InjectMocks
    private static ProductSupplierRestController productSupplierRestController = new ProductSupplierRestController();

    private static MockMvc mockMvc =  MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(productSupplierRestController)
            .setControllerAdvice(new ServiceExceptionHandler()).build();

    // tests
}
```

Is it good practice to make controller and mockMvc static?

Answer (score 0):

If you use JUnit then use annotation @BeforeClass instead of @Before. Method with this annotation will be invoked once before all tests in class.

Comment: To use @BeforeClass, that method have to be static, so controller and mockmvc object should also be static. I tried that too but it gives initialization error.